# Using MCAP for URDFs

Tags: foxglove-studio, mcap, urdf

I'm having trouble with the transportability of my URDF files. Specifically I'm unable to get them to load in Foxglove Studio. Is it possible to add a URDF as an attachment in an MCAP file so that it's somehow fully encapsulated and just opens by robot definition at the same time as visualizing my robot data?

I've tried opening my URDF file directly in Foxglove Studio's web client and it fails. I seem to be able to open it in the desktop tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the work in progress here: https://github.com/foxglove/studio/pull/4725

The basic idea is all asset fetch() requests go through a proxy function in the Studio data source (player). For MCAP, the player checks for an attachment with the name equal to the requested URL, such as package://foo/bar.dae and returns that if present, otherwise falling back to fetch().